# C++ parallel/multithreaded modify vector in place

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, parallel-processing

I am trying to modify a vector in place using multiple threads. It is a very simple operation— subtracting 1 from each index, but speed is highest priority here since both the vector size and number of times I need to do this operation can be quite large (10k elements, 500 increments). Right now I have loops of the sort:

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> my_vec(10000);
    fill(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), 10);

    for (int i = my_vec.size(); i--; ;) {
        my_vec[i] -= 1;   
    }
 
}
```

I am coming back to C/C++ after several years working primarily in R, where splitting this embarrassingly parallel loop across multiple threads is trivial (i.e., each of n threads operates over a portion of the indices, and then concatenate the results).

How can I do this best in C++ that a) avoids copying of the entire vector, and b) is not ultimately slower than the original loop?

Comment: This is not large at all. I can fit 20 of your vectors on my machine's L1 cache.

Comment: Sure. Are you saying that there will not be a speed advantage to multithreading?

Comment: I dont say anything without measuring but I started writing a benchmark for this and there are a few issues. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/7bhrozn5Y   For a vector of 10,000 elements, that takes about 1 microsecond. And just to start a thread it takes anywhere from 3-5 microseconds.  To eliminate that start time impact you have to use a thread pool but that is way more evolving.

Comment: You could perhaps use OpenMP to parallelize the loop or use pstl (on LLVM) that is a parallel STL implementation.

Comment: If you run a program decrementing 10k `int` 500 times, I'm willing to bet you won't notice the running time.

Comment: There is also the issue that as the entire vector fits in L1 cache, if you place even another thread, it will cause cache contention and frequent misses which I predict will hit performance very hard.

Comment: std::transform(execution::par_unseq, my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), my_vec.begin(), [](int a){return a-1;});

Answer (score 0):

As I expected, this is purely a memory I/O problem for the given size of your vector.

I took your initial example and built an AVX2-enabled version and it does not fare much better than a simple loop - it might be that the simple loop gets optimized with AVX too btw.

The reverse loop:

```cpp
  for (int i = my_vec.size(); i--;) {
      my_vec[i] -= 1;   
  }
```

The forward loop:

```cpp
    for ( int i = 0; i<my_vec.size(); ++i ) {
        my_vec[i] -= 1;
    }
```

The AVX2 unaligned loop:

```cpp
        __m256i* ptr = (__m256i*)my_vec.data();
        constexpr size_t per_block = sizeof(__m256i)/sizeof(int);
        size_t num_blocks = my_vec.size() / per_block;
        size_t remaining = my_vec.size() % per_block;
        __m256i ones = _mm256_set1_epi32( 1 );
        for ( size_t j=0; j<num_blocks; ++j, ++ptr ) {
            __m256i val = _mm256_lddqu_si256( ptr );
            val = _mm256_sub_epi32( val, ones );
            _mm256_storeu_si256( ptr, val );
        }
```

The AVX2 aligned loop:

```cpp
        __m256i* ptr = (__m256i*)my_vec.data();
        constexpr size_t per_block = sizeof(__m256i)/sizeof(int);
        size_t num_blocks = my_vec.size() / per_block;
        size_t remaining = my_vec.size() % per_block;
        __m256i ones = _mm256_set1_epi32( 1 );
        for ( size_t j=0; j<num_blocks; ++j, ++ptr ) {
            __m256i val = _mm256_load_si256( ptr );
            val = _mm256_sub_epi32( val, ones );
            _mm256_store_si256( ptr, val );
        }
```

The tests run pretty much at the same elapsed time range

```bash
Test:reverse Elapsed:0.295494 ticks/int
Test:forward Elapsed:0.313866 ticks/int
Test:avx2forward Elapsed:0.367432 ticks/int
Test:avx2aligned Elapsed:0.298912 ticks/int
```

The entire test is here: https://godbolt.org/z/MWjrorncs

As far as why this is a memory-limited problem, your array fits entirely in any L1 cache existent today. As the L1 cache is local to a core, adding threads will only make it worse because it will increase the contention for memory between threads. You can see for example the [main solution for high throughput fizzbuzz at Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/215216/high-throughput-fizz-buzz) is single threaded for this exact reason.

Comment: This is excellent. Thank you for this! It seems like pursuing this isn't a good path for optimization. Although, I'm not entirely sure I fully understand the AVX2 syntax... looks like just pointer arithmetic?